# Sublime Test 2 RubyTest not showing any results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2

I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial. When testing RubyTest (CMD+Shift+R; CMD+Shift+T; CMD+Shift+E) in Sublime Text 2, nothing shows up. The window opens below my files where the tests should be, and it says "Building", but then the "Building" disappears and nothing is left. No test, no green, red, nothing.

I have added RubyTest as described, as well as opened from Command Line as outlined. Need more help troubleshooting.

Using OSX Lion, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.10. My Guard and Spork testing are fine. My RubyTest settings are as per [RubyTest.sublime-settings](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests/blob/master/RubyTest.sublime-settings)

Any thoughts or places to start? I'm pretty new to this, but damn stubborn so I would like to solve as oppose to just "move on". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: no, i've just been using the rspec spec command in terminal for now. Took a break in the lessons to ramp up on ruby coding specifically, but would still love some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have the right solution for you, as I've just run into the same problem and solved it.

First, find out what's causing the `"Building..."` error with RubyTest by digging into the Sublime Text 2 console (`View > Show Console`).

This was my console output:

```
Running rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb -l15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File "./exec.py", line 154, in run
  File "./exec.py", line 45, in __init__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
reloading /Users/Jonathan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/RubyTest.last-run
```

Taken from [here](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/120265-non-ascii-character-bug-in-build-system-using-shell-true/), it turns out ST2 tries to evaluate all shell expressions.

From the same link, here's how I fixed it: go to `Library > Application Support > Sublime Text 2 > Packages > Default` and edit `exec.py` starting at the `for` loop at line 45:

```
for k, v in proc_env.iteritems():
    path_vars = os.path.expandvars(v)
    if isinstance(path_vars, unicode):
        path_vars = path_vars.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
        proc_env[k] = path_vars
```

Hope this solved your problem!

Comment: It didn't quite work. Now the "Building" part is gone, yet still no results. I replaced "line 45", which was     proc_env[k] = os.path.expandvars(v).encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())  with your code. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: sorry, I just can't seem to get the commenting down right. I'll keep working on it, but hopefully you can get the gist of my question.

Comment: There should be a `for` loop around line 45, just replace that entire `for` loop with the code snippet.

Comment: tried again but couldn't get it. Then tried with this one that you helped lead me to.  [link](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8512)  so thanks very much.